# how should look url with two or more query params

Tags: mocking, stub, query-string, stubbing, wiremock

I'm puzzled, how should look my "urlPathPattern" when using two or more query params

My code:

```
"request": {
"method": "POST",
"urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/{cashbox_id}/registration/{registration_id}",
"queryParameters": {
  "cashbox_id": {
    "equalTo": "1"
  }
}
```

how url should look like:

```
POST
http://BaseUrl/cashboxes/1/registration/1
```

I understand that it don't work. Tell me, how fix my urlPathPattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlPathPattern` takes regular expressions, not URL templates.

Try something like: `/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration/[0-9]+`